# При создание нового приложения на Rails и старте ошибка загрузки sqlite3 без явной записи версии

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite3, bundler

Делал проект (тестовый но большой), подключил несколько библиотек, почти все для front-end'a и тут понеслось. Сам проект лягнул из следуещой ошибкой:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       89: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
>       88: from bin/rails:3:in`load'
>       87: from /home/samson/Ruby/trello/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
>       86: from /home/samson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in`require'
>       85: from /home/samson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
>       84: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`'
>       83: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
>       82: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in`'
>       81: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
>       80: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in`call'
>       79: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
>       78: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`load'
>       77: from /home/samson/Ruby/trello/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
>       76: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in`require'
>       75: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
>       74: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in`block in require'
>       73: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
>       72: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in`require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       71: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
>       70: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in`block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       69: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
>       68: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in`'
>       67: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
>       66: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in`perform'
>       65: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
>       64: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
>       63: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
>       62: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in`perform'
>       61: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
>       60: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in`block in perform'
>       59: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
>       58: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in`load_dependency'
>       57: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
>       56: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in`require'
>       55: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       54: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in`register'
>       53: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       52: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in`require'
>       51: from /home/samson/Ruby/trello/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
>       50: from /home/samson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:114:in`require'
>       49: from /home/samson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
>       48: from /home/samson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in`each'
>       47: from /home/samson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
>       46: from /home/samson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`each'
>       45: from /home/samson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
>       44: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in`require'
>       43: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       42: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in`register'
>       41: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       40: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in`require'
>       39: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap.rb:75:in `<main>'
>       38: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap.rb:11:in`load!'
>       37: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap.rb:61:in `register_rails_engine'
>       36: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in`require'
>       35: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
>       34: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in`block in require'
>       33: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
>       32: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in`require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       31: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
>       30: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in`block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       29: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
>       28: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap/engine.rb:4:in`'
>       27: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
>       26: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in`load_dependency'
>       25: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
>       24: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in`require'
>       23: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       22: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in`register'
>       21: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       20: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in`require'
>       19: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.0/lib/sassc-rails.rb:3:in `<main>'
>       18: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in`require_relative'
>       17: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
>       16: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in`load_dependency'
>       15: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
>       14: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in`require'
>       13: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       12: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in`register'
>       11: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>       10: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in`require'
>        9: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.0/lib/sassc/rails.rb:5:in `<main>'
>        8: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in`require'
>        7: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
>        6: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in`block in require'
>        5: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:25:in `require'
>        4: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:36:in`rescue in require'
>        3: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>        2: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:80:in`register'
>        1: from /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>   /home/samson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in`require': cannot load such file -- sassc (LoadError)

что и куда не знаю, гуглить не помогло, такой проблемы  никто не имел.
А вот отсюда, вилезла собственно главная проблема. При создании нового проекта и его старта матерится на sqlite3 без явной записи версии.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при релоаде страницы имею следующие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот три главных вопроса:

1) что делать со второй ошибкой? не охота ручками постоянно прописовать нужную версию + может бить ещо где то трабл с чем-то ... собственно что бы все было как ранше, создал - запусли - работает-все.

2) пробовал все снести, только rmv оставил, и все с нуля установил, но не помогло, то в зависимости оставшиеся или что, но все же не работает как должно ..... вопрос, как правильно переустановить все, все все. С нуля начать?

3) как бить с первой проблемой?

Спасибо

P.S.
сильно не пинайте, учусь все же

Gemfile проекта которий все запорол:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Gemfile нового проекта, коменти удалил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите gem файл

Comment: А после каких именно изменений всё упало? Что добавили в гемфайл?

Comment: bundle install нормально прошёл? Вы гемсетами пользуетесь при установке гемов или всё в кучу ставите? Какую версию sqlite3 даёт `gem list`?

Comment: @Василиса bundle продит нормально;
нет, как то не приходилось, не на том уровне пока что;
sqlite3 (1.4.0, 1.3.13)

Comment: @Axelrod, ответьте на два первых коммента тоже :) Удалите более старую версию гема  `gem uninstall sqlite3  --version 1.1.9`

Comment: @Василиса удалил, все тот же еррор;
упало точно не скажу, но после devise,  administrate, sidekiq gems, ну и bootstrap добавил. После все их удалил но не помогло.

Comment: @Axelrod, только сейчас увидела, что копипастила код `uninstall` и там стоит левый номер версии. Вы же его исправили и сейчас `gem list` даёт всего одну версию sqlite3, и всё равно та же ошибка?

Comment: @ да,заметил, осталась только версия 1.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вызвана Active Record, в которой есть ограничение версии гема sqlite3. Для Rails 5.2.2 это `~> 1.3.6`. Так как это ограничение не прописано в gemspec, то Bundler устанавливает последнюю версию, 1.4.0, которая конфликтует с AR.

Этот недочёт уже исправили, и он выйдет в Rails 5.2.3. Пока же самый простой вариант решения - ограничить версию sqlite3 в гемфайле.

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
```

Не забудьте удалить 1.4.0

```
gem uninstall sqlite3 --version 1.4.0
```